# HtmlTextWriter Output attribute with Single quotes

Tags: c#, jquery, htmltextwriter

I need to output an attribute with single quotes using htmltextwriter.

Any idea how to achieve this?  I've writter the whole file already using htmltextwriter - so I do want to use this object to generate the file.  Maybe override it?  It needs to be able to accomodate a jquery plugin and I don't want to hack around with the plugin.

```
  <div class="shopname" data-groups='["shopsnz", "aam" ]'>

            htmlWriter.AddAttribute("data-groups", ???? 
            htmlWriter.RenderBeginTag("div"); // div1
```

thanks :-)

Comment: Try `htmlWriter.AddAttribute("data-groups", " 'YourValue' ");`

Comment: Nope. 

<div class="shopname" data-groups=" '[&quot;shopsnz&quot;,&quot;deva&quot;] '">

Comment: No it's not. I hacked around it by getting the whole document and Regex.replace  .. but that is a real hack .. didn't do it through the htmltextwriter